# UITabBarController present VC at tab index 1

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I need to present the VC linked to the 2nd tab (index: 1) of a UITabBarController. Without using the storyboard segues.

With segues it is working. The code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let tabVC = segue.destination as? UITabBarController 
    tabVC.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

Without using segues my code looks like (see below). On presenting the tabVC the first (index: 0) tab is presented although I set the selectedIndex to 1 (second tab). Any suggestions to get this solved? Thanks

```
func presentTab1(_ sender: Any) {

    let tabVC =  MainTabBar() 
    tabVC.selectedIndex = 1

    present(tabVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: you can use UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning.

Comment: elaborate your question.

Comment: Do you want your app to launch with a TabBar, but starting at the 2nd tab instead of the 1st tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do there are two approaches, you can use anyone of them

1.) If you have **NavigationController** then try below line of code in your function.

```
func presentTab1(_ sender: Any) {
    let targetVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigateionControllerIdentifier") as! UINavigationController
    self.present(targetVC, animated: true)
}
```

2.) Or if you want to navigate directly to **ViewConteroller** then

```
func presentTab1(_ sender: Any) {
    let targetVC = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerIdentifier"))!
    self.present(targetVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: thanks but where do initiate the Storyboard Indentifier "viewControllerIdentifier"?

Comment: Set StoryBoard ID as viewControllerIdentifier in Identity Inspector

Comment: I'm NOT using the storyboard !!! Do you know a way to set the StoryboardID in code

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, you Can do it like this:

```
func presentTab1(_ sender: Any) {
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
    _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

works greta for me!
You just need to know which index you want to visit.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest passing the selected index into your constructor and setting the SelectedIndex in ViewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Give a name to your View controller to which you want to go.
Select that view controller and from here give an identity of that VC
[image]

**Step 2:**

Navigate to that VC using the following code :

```
let targetVC = 
(self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someVC"))!
self.present(targetVC, animated: true)
```

if you have navigation controller then.

```
let targetVC = 
self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationControllerId") as! UINavigationController
self.present(targetVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: I'm NOT using the storyboard !!! Do you know a way to set the StoryboardID in code ?

Comment: did u make tab bar controller by code? and as well as child view controller?

Comment: let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: nil)